# Koa Session: MySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

How does one hook up koa-session to a mysql store?  It doesn't look like a mysql-store has been developed yet, so I suppose I could develop that.  Are there any other solutions other than building out the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from my previous answer, I have published this code onto github and npm.  The code shouldn't be ahrd tp extend to other relational DBs:

https://github.com/tb01923/koa-mysql-session

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to build a mysql koa sessions store following the connect [mysql-session-store](https://github.com/sugendran/mysql-session-store/blob/master/index.js) logic / SQL.  I am also looking at [koa-redis](https://github.com/koajs/koa-redis/blob/master/lib/koa-redis.js) and [koa-generic-session/memory_store](https://github.com/koajs/generic-session/blob/master/lib/memory_store.js) for approach. Essentially the session store presents an object with get(sid) and set(sid, obj) methods.

Both koa session store objects have these signatures:

```
Store.prototype.get = function *(sid) {
  return session;
};

Store.prototype.set = function *(sid, val, ttl) { };
Store.prototype.destroy = function *(sid) { };
```

Therefore I coded these up:

```
MysqlStore.prototype.get = function *(sid) {
    let connection = this.getConnection()
    let results = yield connection.query(GET_STATEMENT, [sid])
    let session = null ;
    if(results && results[0] && results[0][0] && results[0][0].data){
        session = JSON.parse(results[0][0].data);
    }
    return session
};

MysqlStore.prototype.set = function *(sid, session, ttl) {
    let expires = getExpiresOn(session, ttl).valueOf()
    let data = JSON.stringify(session);
    let connection = this.getConnection()
    let results = yield connection.query(SET_STATEMENT, [sid, expires, data, expires, data])
    return results
};

MysqlStore.prototype.destroy = function *(sid) {
    let connection = this.getConnection()
    let results = yield connection.query(DELETE_STATEMENT, [sid])
};
```

With the constructor responsible for the mysql connection pool (via [co-mysql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/co-mysql)) and setting up the table in the DB for the session:

```
var MysqlStore = function (options) {
    this.getConnection = function(){
        let connection = mysql.createPool(options) ;
        return connection ;
    }

    this.setup = co(function*() {
        let connection = this.getConnection()
        let result = yield connection.query(CREATE_STATEMENT)
    })

    this.setup()
};
```

At some point I will seek some advice to publish this solution on github and NPM.  I want to make sure I am honoring the used libraries and licenses first. The project will be here: https://github.com/tb01923/koa-mysql-session